# Change item of a session array in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.6, laravel-session

I'm using `Laravel 5.6`, using `session` array to store the user details after login.

```
user_date = array:19 [
  "userEmail" => "user@user.com"
  "username" => "userwebtest"
  "role" => "user"
  "gender" => "male"
  "profilePic" => "https://domain/public/images/male.jpg"
  "temporaryMobile" => null
  "communicationEmail" => "user@user.com"
  "userId" => "---"
  "registrationDate" => "2018-08-22T07:37:59.603Z"
  "emailVerified" => false
  "__v" => 0
  "mobile" => "---"
  "cart" => []
  "socialLinks" => []
]
```

Now, when on some event, say `update` mobile number after OTP verification I just want to update the mobile object.

If I do this `Session::put("user_data['temporaryMobile']",'+91'.$request->get('new_number'));`, it will overwrite the entire object.

So all I can think of doing is `$data = Session::get('user_data')` & update the `$data` array and then put it back to the session `Session::put("user_data",$data)`

I hope there's a better solution to this, looking for a solution where we can just alter the array item without storing the data in different variable.

TIA

Comment: @ankitpatel I think your comment should be an answer instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use dot notation

```
Session::put('user_data.temporaryMobile','yourmobilenumber');
```

so this way you don't need to overwrite entire user data.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this:

```
Session::put('user_data.temporaryMobile','yourmobilenumber');
```

**OR**

```
Session::push('user_data.temporaryMobile','yourmobilenumber');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **Session** faced :

`Session::put('user_data.temporaryMobile','yourmobilenumber');`

Using global **session()** :

you can override multiple items

```
$user= session('user_data');
$user['temporaryMobile'] = 'yourmobilenumber';
session(['user_data'=>$user]);
```